# asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, ssl

i have this website, and this specific page is secure, but when it postbacks, it postbacks to an unsecure page.  How to fix that?!

I am using ASP.NET Wizard.  I have this page - checkout.aspx, and this control checkout.ascx contained by the page.  Now, the encode to ensure ssl is inside the page like this:

```
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
         if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection) {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(SiteNavigation.ResolveAbsoluteUrl(true, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
            }

    }
```

The wizard is inside checkout.ascx control.  Now, it uses postbacks to go to the next step, but it postbacks to an insecure page (meaning it drops "s" from https), which hits my ensuresslenabled code, and it redirects itself to the checkout page again.

Comment: The "action" attribute of your <form> tag determines this. As your title mentions asp.net, there's some magic going on probably. You will need to post a code sample to get a useful answer.

Comment: I have provided some more detail in my question now.  Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Still need more info. What is going on in Utils.EnsureSSLEnabled()?

Comment: I replaced that with the function definition itself.

SiteNavigation.ResolveAbsoluteUrl(...) funciton in merely appending 's' to http, and it's not messing up the url, because I can see the right url in front of me.

Comment: Sorry, still not enough info. Do you have any values specified for any of the *Url properties of the wizard control, or something else? Or a hard-coded action using http://? By default it will post back to the same page.

Comment: No, I could not find anything like that on my wizard.  Other people are using similar wizards for themselves, and it is working for them, so either they are doing special, or I am missing something. But, according to you, an ASP.NET wizard would not lose it's 'https' while navigating to other steps?

Comment: That's certainly my experience with ASP.net controls in general. Admittedly, however, I do not have a lot of experience with the wizard--I think I only used it once, and that was not in an SSL context. I'm not able to test anything on this end right now (no SSL available) but maybe later I can at least confirm the behavior? Sorry I couldn't help any better.

Comment: no, you tried a lot. For now, I am stripping down my code to bare minimum and build on from there, to see what's going on. I might post more questions related to this topic within a couple of hours, so keep an eye out for asp.net wizard, if you can lol.

Comment: Update: The bare minimum asp:Wizard does not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps find any instances of hardcoded `http:` in the related code. Usually a postback will respect the protocol being used.

Answer (score -1):

If the user is not logged in, he will be redirected to an unsecured page like login/register page. Make your question more clear.

Comment: Question was edited after my answer. Earlier the question comprised of just one line shown above.